# How to display response in html nodejs-->angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I'm new to NodeJS and AngularJS. Objective is to retrieve response from external site and display in Angular JS.

I could send the request and get response but in UI JSON printed as string with forward slash "\". like
"{\"count\":3,\"page\":1,\"pageSize\":50,\"links\":{\"self\":{\"href\":\"/v1/campaigns\"}},\"items\":[{\"createdDate\":\"2017-06-08T00:50:20\",\"modifiedDate\":\"2017-06-29T09:35:46\",\"id\":\"523\",\"name\":\"ACT BB Annual Sale 2018\",\"description\":\"Yearly sale\",\"campaignCode\":\"annual2018\",\"color\":\"d7edad\",\"favorite\":false},{\"createdDate\":\"2017-06-08T00:50:20\",\"modifiedDate\":\"2017-06-29T09:35:46\",\"id\":\"489\",\"name\":\"Test_Namrata\",\"description\":\"Test prupose\",\"campaignCode\":\"\",\"color\":\"ffc7c7\",\"favorite\":false},{\"createdDate\":\"2017-06-08T00:50:20\",\"modifiedDate\":\"2017-06-29T09:35:46\",\"id\":\"172\",\"name\":\"Welcome\",\"description\":\"\",\"campaignCode\":\"WL0007\",\"color\":\"ffc7c7\",\"favorite\":false}]}"

1. `Index` is the UI file
2. `App.js` file has the logic for sending req and getting response.

code of `Index.html`

```
<html>
<head>
     <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
     <link rel="icon"  type="image/icon"  href="Node.ico" />
</head>

<body ng-app="postgreSQL">
    <div class="container" style="margin-top:20px;"  ng-      
       controller="postgreSQLCtrl">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-12 column">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <h1>
                        Heroku + PostgreSQL Using Nodejs
                    </h1>
                    <p>
                        This application demonstrates Simple DB operations  
                        using PG SQL as a database, Heroku as platform,  
                        Node.js as language and Angularjs as javascript 
                        based MVC.
                        <br /> <br />
                        <a class="pull-right" href="http://id.heroku.com"> 
                        Suresh PJ 
                        </a> 
                    </p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row clearfix" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
            <div class="controls form-inline form-group">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input id="cName" name="cName"  
                           placeholder="Campaign Name" ng-model="cName" 
                           type="text" class="form-control input-small"> 
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input id="cDescription" 
                           name="cDescription" 
                           placeholder="Campaign Description" 
                           ng-model="cDescription"
                           type="text" class="form-control input-small"> 
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input id="cCode" name="cCode"  
                           placeholder="Campaign Code" ng-model="cCode"
                           type="text" class="form-control input-small"> 
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input id="cColor" name="cColor"  
                           placeholder="Campaign Color" ng-model="cColor"
                           type="text" class="form-control input-small"> 
                </div>                    

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input id="cFavorite" name="cFavorite"  
                           placeholder="Campaign Favorite" 
                           ng-model="cFavorite"
                           type="text" class="form-control input-small"> 
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button ng-click="getAllRec()" id="btnAdd" 
                     name="btnAdd" class="btn btn-danger">Add</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row clearfix" ng-app="postgreSQL" 
              ng-controller="postgreSQLCtrl"> 
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>  Id  </th>
                        <th> Campaign Name </th>
                        <th> Campaign Description </th>
                        <th>  Campaign Code </th>
                        <th>  Campaign Color </th>
            <th>  Campaign Favorite </th>
                        <th>   </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="item in dataset">
                        <td> {{item.items.id}} </td>
                        <td> {{item.items.name}} </td>
                        <td> {{item.items.description}} </td>
                        <td> {{item.items.campaignCode}} </td>
                        <td> {{item.items.color}} </td>
            <td> {{item.items.favorite}} </td>
                        <td> <span title="delete this record" 
                          class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash text-danger" 
                          style="cursor:pointer" 
                          ng-click="delRecord(item.id)"></span> </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>                
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="lib/angular.min.js"> </script>
    <script>

        var myApp = angular.module('postgreSQL',[ ]); 
        myApp.controller('postgreSQLCtrl', ['$scope' ,'$http', 
                          function($scope,$http) {

            $scope.cName = '';
            $scope.cDescription = '';
            $scope.cCode = '';
            $scope.cColor = '';
            $scope.cFavorite = '';              


            $scope.getAllRec = function(){ 
                                    $http ({
                method: 'GET',
                url: "/hub/v1/campaigns"                    
                }). success(function(data, status) { 
                  alert('AngularJS success scope: ');
                                      $scope.dataset = data; 
                  alert($scope.dataset);
                                    }).
                                    error(function(data, status) {
                  alert('AngularJS error scope: ');
                                      $scope.dataset = data || "Request 
                                      failed "; 
                  alert($scope.dataset);
                                    }); 
                           } //end of scope getAllRec                   
        }); //end of myApp controller

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

code of `App.js`

```
var express = require('express'),
http = require('http'),
request = require('request'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
errorHandler = require('express-error-handler'),
corsOrigin = require ('cors'),
typeis = require('type-is'),
bearerToken = require('express-bearer-token');
app = express();

var dbOperations = require("./dbOperations.js");
var logFmt = require("logfmt");

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views') ;

app.use(bearerToken({
    bodyKey: 'access_token',
    queryKey: 'access_token',
    headerKey: 'Bearer',
    reqKey: 'abc'
}));

app.use(corsOrigin());
app.use(bearerToken());

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

request ({
    uri: 'https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/campaigns',
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer abc,
           'content-type': 'application/json'}
        },
    function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && res.statusCode === 200) {                         
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            res.write(JSON.stringify(body));
            console.log(body);              
            res.sendfile('views/index.html');
            res.end();

        }
        else { res.json (error);
        }    
    }); //end of request

} ); //end of app.get root

app.get('/hub/v1/campaigns', function(req,res) {

    request ({
        uri: 'https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/campaigns',
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer abc',
               'content-type': 'application/json'}
        },
        function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && res.statusCode === 200) {
            console.log(body);

            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            res.write(JSON.stringify(body));                
            res.sendfile('views/index.html');
            res.end();
        }
        else { res.json (error);
        }   

    }); //end of request    

}); // end of app /hub/v1/campaigns


var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
app.listen(port);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client')); 
app.use(errorHandler());
app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + port);
});

module.exports = express;
```

Regards,
SPJ

Comment: Please edit your post to format things properly. It's pretty unreadable in its current state.

Comment: unreadable. edit & format your code please.

Comment: Hello Lex and JDOaktown. I have formatted the code. what i do not understand is that how does App.js pass the result (response) back to index.html.

Comment: Do you have data in `$scope.dataset` after request?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're successfully able to retrieve data from your backend. What missing is to let the angularjs know the root element of your app which is done using `ng-app` directive.

You've already defined module just use it here

```
<div class="row clearfix" ng-app="postgreSQL">
```

You also need to invoke your controller of your app here like

```
 <div class="row clearfix" ng-app="postgreSQL" ng-controller="postgreSQLCtrl">
```

Now your app is ready for data binding an other angularjs perks

Comment: Thanks for your reply George. I have ng-app and ng-controller added but the result is JSON printed as string in the UI. The response for the request in App.js is not passing back to index.html.

Comment: Add this too `$scope.dataset = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: Added `$scope.dataset = JSON.parse(data)` but the result is still the same meaning following displayed on the browser "{\"count\":3,\"page\":1,\"pageSize\":50,\"links\":{\"self\":{\"href\":\"/v1/campaigns\"}},\"items\":[{\"createdDate\":\"2017-06-08T00:50:20\",\"modifiedDate\":\"2017-06-29T09:35:46\",\"id\":\"523\",\"name\":\"ACT BB Annual Sale 2018\",\"description\":\"Yearly sale\",\"campaignCode\":\"annual2018\",\"color\":\"d7edad\",\"favorite\":false}]}". Looks like need to replace "\" with space.